# Promise.allSettled - set time delay to avoid API Abuse Rate Limits

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm working with Promise.allSettled to do multiple fetches to the Github API for a few hundred requests. I'm getting blocked as they're all getting called at once, so I want to add a delay of 5ms between each. Is this possible with Promise.allSettled?

Comment: No, it is not. `Promise.allSettled` only waits for promises you already created, whose requests are already in flight. What you need is a delay in the actual looping.

Answer (score 3):

`allSettled` will neither help nor hinder you; it has no logic at all with regard to timing, other than to wait for the promises to settle. It will be up to you to create your promises so that they have the delays you want.

For example:

```
const delay = (milliseconds) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);

const urls = ['www.foo.com/whatever', /* etc for a few hundred urls */];
const promises = urls.map((url, index) => {
  return delay(index * 5)
    .then(() => fetch(url))
})

Promise.allSettled(promises)
  .then(results => {
    // do whatever with the results
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need a concurrency limit, not a delay.
Fetch with concurrency limit:
[Plain JS demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-curran-9ugbv)

```
const urls = [
  "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=3s&foo1",
  "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=3s&foo2",
  "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=3s&foo3",
  "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=3s&foo4",
  "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=3s&foo5",
  "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=3s&foo6",
  "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=3s&foo7"
];

function fetchBottleneck(concurrency = 1) {
  const queue = [];
  let pending = 0;
  return async (...args) => {
    if (pending === concurrency) {
      await new Promise((resolve) => queue.push(resolve));
    }

    pending++;

    return fetch(...args).then((value) => {
      pending--;
      queue.length && queue.shift()();
      return value;
    });
  };
}

// Use fetch queue
(async () => {
  const fetchInQueue = fetchBottleneck(3);
//No matter how many times you call the 'fetchInQueue' method, you get a maximum of 3 pending requests at the same time.

  const results = await Promise.all(
    urls.map(async (url) => {
      try {
        const response = await fetchInQueue(url);
        console.log(`Got response for ${url}`);
        return { status: "fulfilled", value: await response.json() };
      } catch (reason) {
        return { status: "rejected", reason };
      }
    })
  );

  console.log("Done:", JSON.stringify(results));
})();
```

Better solution is to use concurrency limitation provided by several third-party libs (e.g. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)

[Live browser example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpromiseallsettled-1gkoe?file=/src/index.js)

```
import CPromise from "c-promise2";

CPromise.allSettled(
  [
    "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=3s&foo1",
    "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=4s&foo2",
    "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=2s&foo3",
    "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=3s&foo4",
    "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=4s&foo5",
    "https://fake.url.to.test/",
    "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=3s&foo6",
    "https://run.mocky.io/v3/40594989-00c2-4798-94da-c4a9ab251558?mocky-delay=3s&foo7"
  ],
  {
    mapper: (url) => {
      console.log(`request [${url}]`);
      return fetch(url).then((response) => response.json());
    },
    concurrency: 2
  }
).then((results) => {
  console.log(`Done: `, JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

Comment: This does something different than what I think the OP asked for.  This makes a request, waits for its response, then inserts a delay, then makes another request and repeats.  There are zero requests running in parallel here - this is entirely serial.  This is also a 5 second delay when the OP asked for 5ms.

Comment: @jfriend00 The author has not explicitly requested any concurrency functionality, but in such a case, he should use a custom promise with concurrency limit or queue instead of monkey code using allSettled and delay, because they doesn't solve anything here. A 5ms latency without monitoring the number of pending requests is useless because no one can guarantee the response time. If the server latency is about 2 seconds, we can get up to 400 concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

This version of `Promise.allSettled` makes use of the `delay` method defined above, but adding a random delay between calls and it let to optionally filter `fulfilled` or `rejected` Promise status:

```js
function allSettledDelayed(promises = [], milliseconds = 100, status = '') {
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    const delay = (milliseconds) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
    try {
        let randomInt = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        promises = promises.map((promise, index) => delay(randomInt(0, (index+1) * milliseconds)).then(() => promise));
      var responses = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
      if (status == "fulfilled" || status == "rejected") responses = responses.filter(p => p.status === status).map(p => p.value);
      return resolve(responses);
    } catch (error) {
      return reject(error);
    }
  });
} //allSettledDelayed

(async() => {
  var urls = Array(10).fill().map((v, i) => `https://httpbin.org/response-headers?key=${i}`);
  const promises = urls.map(url => fetch(url).then((response) => response.status))
  var res = await allSettledDelayed(promises, 300, '')
  console.log(res)
})();
```